# Xamarin - Render array of object in form with submit button

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin and I wanted to develop a screen which basically renders multiple sections like this screen [UI Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqxZf.png), and on click of submit button, I want all entered object on server side.

class which is bind to form will be a list of Products.

```
Public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string ProductName { get; set;}
   public int Quantity { get; set;}
}
```

**User will enter quantity for each of product line.**

On click of submit button how I will get entire object (including entered quantity) on server side.

Comment: use a CollectionView or ListView.  This is far too broad to be answered succinctly.  You need to try to do this yourself and ask specific questions about problems you encounter, not broad questions that expect a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `CollectionView` or `ListView` to achieve this function.

I achieved this function with `ListView` and [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/), you can refer to the following code:

1.create a view model(`ProductViewModel.cs`)

```
public class ProductViewModel
{

    // add SubmitCommand  for submit button
    public ICommand SubmitCommand { protected set; get; } 
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Items { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel() {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

        Items.Add(new Product {Id = 1, ProductName = "Tomato", Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Product {Id = 2, ProductName = "Romaine Lettuce", Quantity = 2 });
        Items.Add(new Product {Id= 3, ProductName = "Zucchini", Quantity = 3 });


        SubmitCommand = new Command(() => { 
           // here we will get the latest value of the binded property
            foreach(var item in Items) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ProductName is: " + item.ProductName+ " <----> Quantity is:  " + item.Quantity);
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

2.create ContentPage (`ProducePage`)

ProducePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FormsListViewSample.ViewModels"
             x:Class="FormsListViewSample.ProducePage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:ProductViewModel></viewmodels:ProductViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <Button  Text="result" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"  />

            <ListView  x:Name="lstView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"   RowHeight="60" HasUnevenRows="False">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />

                                    <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />

                                </StackLayout>
                                <Entry Text="{Binding Quantity}"   FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />

                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```